# Como juntar 2 columnas en un datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

Lo que sucede es que cuando lleno una tabla utilizando el plugin data tables no quiero que por ejemplo el apellido paterno ni materno ni el segundo nombre aparezcan en columnas separadas  sino que  aparezca todo en una sola columna,
¿Como puedo unir las columnas que necesito?

```
options = {
dom: "Bfrtip",
ajax: (data, callback, settings) => {
  this.servicioUsuarios.getUsuarios().subscribe(data => {
    callback({
      aaData: data
    })
  }, e => {
    this.notificaciones.notificacionError(e);
  });
},
columns: [
  { data: "id" },
  { data: "login" },
  { data: "nombre" },
  { data: "correo" },
  { data: "fechaAlta" },
  // { "defaultContent": "<button >Click!</button>"}
],
```

Answer (score 3):

Puedes trabajarlo por posición y hacer una concatenación.

Dentro del `render` puedes hacer lo que quieras y con el `return` imprimir lo que quieres q se visualice.

```
options = {
dom: "Bfrtip",
ajax: (data, callback, settings) => {
  this.servicioUsuarios.getUsuarios().subscribe(data => {
    callback({
      aaData: data
    })
  }, e => {
    this.notificaciones.notificacionError(e);
  });
},
columns: [
  { data: "id" },
  { data: "login" },
  { data: "nombre" },
  {"render":
        function ( data, type, row ) {
            return (row[3] + ' ' + row[4] + ' ' + row[5] + ' ' + row[6]);
            // donde, en teoría:
            // row[3] es 'primer_nombre'
            // row[4] es 'segundo_nombre'
            // row[5] es 'apellido_paterno'
            // row[6] es 'apellido_materno'
        }
  }, 
  { data: "correo" },
  { data: "fechaAlta" },
  // { "defaultContent": "Click!"}
],
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, si funciono

Comment: Amigo tilda la respuesta que te dio solución para que mas nadie le busque otra solución y me colaboras con un +1 ;)

Comment: Funciona de la manera "return (row[3] + ' ' + row[4] + ' ' + row[5] + ' ' + row[6]);" pero no toma el indexado real del bufer de la consulta, en mi casa ocupaba row 5 y 6 y tomo como indexado hasta la 8 y 9 (3 columnas de diferencia)

Answer (score 0):

**Concatena los campos bien en tu datatables o en tu sentencia sql**

```
 options = {
    dom: "Bfrtip",
    ajax: (data, callback, settings) => {
      this.servicioUsuarios.getUsuarios().subscribe(data => {
        callback({
          aaData: data
        })
      }, e => {
        this.notificaciones.notificacionError(e);
      });
    },
    columns: [
      { data: "id" },
      { data: "login" },
      { data: "nombre" +" "+"segundo_mobre"+" "+"apellido_materno"+" "+"apellido_paterno"},
      { data: "correo" },
      { data: "fechaAlta" },
      // { "defaultContent": "<button >Click!</button>"}
    ],
```

Comment: No se puede marca un error en el datatables,    DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Requested unknown parameter 'nombre segundoapellido' for row 0, column 2. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

Comment: puedes copiarlo como lo escribistes? por te sale un espacio??